# Core data - Collection __NSCFSet was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

Application crashes while inserting the data into core data.
There are more then 500 records going to insert into the database. Initially check condition if messageId not exit in database then insert the record in database. 
But application crash on

BOOL isExist = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

with the error Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x16f601c0> was mutated while being enumerated.'

```
 appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *writerObjectContext = appDelegate.writerManagedObjectContext;
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    temporaryContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext;
    [temporaryContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error;
        for (StreamData *stream in streamData) {
            NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:DB_TABLE_STREAM];
            [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stream_id = %@", stream.messageId]];
            [request setFetchLimit:1];
            BOOL isExist = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

            if (!isExist) {
                CF_Stream *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:DB_TABLE_STREAM inManagedObjectContext:context];
                [object setStream_id:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[stream.messageId longLongValue]]];
                [object setType:stream.streamType];
                [object setTime_stamp:[[DateTimeManager sharedInstances] getStreamDate:stream.streamTime]];
            }
            if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
        if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        [managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            [writerObjectContext performBlock:^{
                NSError *error = nil;
                if (![writerObjectContext save:&error])  {
                    completionBlock(NO);
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    abort();
                } else {
                    completionBlock(YES);
                }
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: Seeing the same problem. Waiting for answers...